# The deferred EL expression is not allowed since deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral is false

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, jsf-1.2

I am trying to an application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0. Basically, I am following those guides:

- [RichFaces 3.3.3 and JSF 2.0](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20), as my application uses RichFaces 3.3
- [Facelets 1.x to Facelets 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532870/238421), since I am using Facelets as presentation technology.

After getting a great deal of the expected errors, I got this unexpected error message (names changed to protect the guilty):

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /mypage.jsp
mypage.jsp:10:36: The deferred EL expression is not allowed since deferredSyntaxAllowedAsLiteral is false.
            <ui:param name="pageTitle" value="#{myBundle.myPageTitle}" />
                                              ^---------------------^
```

Does this error mean I have fallen back to JSP presentation technology?

Comment: JSF 2 didn't support jsp. Try rename file in mypage.xhtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing Facelets specific tags `<ui:xxx>` inside a JSP file instead of a Facelets (XHTML) file.

This is indeed not going to work. That piece of code is basically interpreted as plain text, it's as if you're writing down plain HTML/XML. You would have gotten exactly the same error if you were using e.g.

```
<p>#{myBundle.myPageTitle}</p>
```

In other words, the EL expression is been interpreted as part of "template text" and the deferred EL form `#{}` is in JSP not supported in template text, only the immediate EL form `${}` is supported in template text.

The solution is rather simple: rename `mypage.jsp` to `mypage.xhtml` and don't forget to replace all other JSP-specific tags like `<%@...%>` and `<jsp:xxx>` by Facelets/XHTML ones.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: I would never have thought that the file name was wrong. Anyway: `.jsp` was wrong even with Facelets 1.x, wasn't it?

Comment: Indeed. The `.jsp` is a special file extension which is recognized by the server's JSP/Servlet container and processed as such before passing the request further to JSF.